# Seaborn countplot show wrong results on Titanic dataset

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm working on the Titanic dataset which I've got it from this website: 
https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/titanic-passengers/table/?flg=fr

I want to show the number of male and female persons for each survived class (yes or no).

First of all I got the whole number of male and female persons using:

```
bysex=data1['Sex'].value_counts()
print(bysex)
```

This gave me these results:

```
male      577
female    314
Name: Sex, dtype: int64
```

The results show that the number of male persons is greater than female persons.

But when I use seaborn to show the number of male and female persons for each survived class using this code:

```
plot1 = sns.FacetGrid(data1, col='Survived')
plot1.map(sns.countplot,'Sex')
```

Then I get this results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAiON.png)

Here it shows that the number of female is greater than the number of male and for no survived class the number of female (around 450) is even greater than the total number of female persons (314).

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is something wrong with the mapping.
In the left plot Sex are interchanged.

```
data1.loc[data1["Survived"] == "No", 'Sex'].value_counts()
male      468
female     81
Name: Sex, dtype: int64
```

and the second plot is right.

```
data1.loc[data1["Survived"] == "Yes", 'Sex'].value_counts()
female    233
male      109
Name: Sex, dtype: int64
```

On the other hand when you use

```
ax = sns.countplot(x="Survived", hue="Sex", data=data1)
```

you get the right results.

[image]